# JQuery calling .click() on an autogenerated img inside

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("picHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","getpic.php?q="+str+"&t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

to pass in data and generate an undefined amount of pictures with the echo from PHP code in getpic.php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<div id=" . $num . "><img src=QR/" . $row['img']".png></div>";
}
```

So these pictures do come out generated, however, now I'm trying to use

```
    $("#img").click(function () { 
        alert("Hi");
    });
```

but nothing gets alerted. The top function posts the stuff in the  however i can't seem to call inside that id? How can I call the div or the img inside the outer div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're generating content asynchronously, `$.click()` won't work unless you manually attach it to each new element. Try using `$.live()` instead:

```
// Applies itself to all <img /> tags.
$("img").live("click",function(){
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Be sure to check your `id`s as well, and note that using integers for your id is not a good practice. If you wish to use the numerical id of the image as the id, preface it with some type of alpha-value, such as `#image19`.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, $("img").live("click",function(){
 did the trick =)

Answer (score 1):

`#`symbol indicates filtering by ID in JQuery way. You need to filter by tag type which means you can use:

```
$("img").live(function () { 
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Also, try to follow HTML rules by covering your attribute values with quotes:

```
echo '<div id="'.$num.'"><img src="QR/'.$row['img'].'.png"></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I was fiddling around with that, and this didn't work b4, but this combined with the answer did the trick =)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('img').live('click',function(){.....`

For one, #img would imply there's a dom node with the id="img" 
For two, any dom nodes added after the domready will not be able to be bound to a click() so you have to use live()

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the click event after your ajax succeeds, OR use the `live` method. Like this:

```
   $("img").live("click", function () { 
        alert("Hi");
    });
```

Note that `"#img"` would select elements with `id="img"`, but `"img"` will select all elements whose tag is `<img ../>`.

Hope this helps. Cheers